# war plugin of gradle not copying files from src/main/java/** to classes folder

Tags: war, gradle

I am migrating build tool from Maven to Gradle for a web-application.

gradle build command is successful.

But, gradle is not copying *.hbm.xml files from src\main\java\** folder to WEB-INF\classes\** folder.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "war"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    hibernateVersion = "3.6.9.Final"
}

dependencies {

    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$slf4jVersion"
    compile "log4j:log4j:1.2.17"

    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion"
    ...
}
```

Comment: The directory `src/main/java` is meant to hold Java source files. Your Hibernate mapping files are considered resource files. They should sit in the directory `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, it works after moving files to resources directory.

Comment: if youmove files to resoruces folder, eclipse stops to recognize them.. and your dvelopment environment gets screwed..